# Are there cleaner methods to handling async http requests than delegation in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, nsurl, delegation

I'm building an iPhone app that heavily leverages a web service I wrote in php. Right now I have a file (API.h/API.m) that has methods which call php functions on my web service through NSURLConnection.

Methods like:

```
-(void) mediaAdd:(UIImage *)image withDelegate: (id<apiRequest>) delegate;
-(void) mediaGet:(NSString *)imageURL withDelegate: (id<apiRequest>) delegate;
```

These methods are called by controllers in the app (controllers defined by the MVC pattern), and the methods take in the controller as the delegate.

Once the request from the called method in API.h/API.m has finished, the NSURLConnection delegate method in API.h/API.m that is called when the request is finished, then calls the delegate method...

```
-(void) serverResponse:(NSDictionary *) response fromCall:(NSString *)call;
```

...which is of course executed on the controller that is calling the method in API.h/API.m.

My problem, or rather disorganization arises when a controller needs to make more than one API call. Because I only have the single delegate method, I differentiate between different calls by using the call parameter in the serverResponse method.

Here's a skeleton of an instance of the serverResponse method:

```
//API Delegate
-(void)serverResponse:(NSDictionary *)response fromCall:(NSString *)call {
    bool local = false;
    NSString *callbackString;
    if (local) {
        callbackString = @"http://localhost/";
    } else {
        callbackString = @"http://secret.com/";
    }
    if ([call isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@user/add",callbackString]]) {
        //user/add was called
        if (![[response objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
            if ([[response objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"fail"]) {
                if ([[response objectForKey:@"reason"] isEqualToString:@"udid already taken"]) {
                     //UDID taken
                }
            } else {

                //UDID not taken, we're good to go



            }

        } else {
            NSLog(@"fail");
        }
    } else if([call isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@moment/get",callbackString]]){
        //moment/get was the api call
    } else if([call isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@printPictures/printPic",callbackString]]){

        //printPictures/printPic was the api call
    } else {
        NSLog(@"wrong call");
    }



}
```

My question is, should I go ahead and take the plunge of making a delegate method for each API call? Or am I overthinking this, and there is actually a really simple method of handling this. Perhaps a design pattern or structure?

Thank you!
- Mike

Comment: Off topic observation, but now looking at the skeleton, I have a lot of redundant code.. haha. Just noting that I notice that, so I do know it's a problem.

Comment: You can pass a completion block instead of a delegate.

Comment: You realize, of course, that you can create more than one delegate *object* for a given delegate protocol?  To solve your problem just create an object for each API call.

Comment: Hot Licks, I mentioned that solution in my question, but I didn't want to go through with it unless it was the last option available.

Comment: @MichaelKing - I don't know why you think that's a bad approach, as it would likely require the least "tear up".  (And, ultimately, all of the techniques mentioned here are using "delegates" -- it's just that the delegates are implemented several different ways.)

Comment: Note that "separate delegate object" is not the same as "separate delegate method".  You can have multiple copies of the same delegate class, implementing the same delegate method.

Comment: @HotLicks okay that I did not think about. It sounds pretty good as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this kind of thing by having a separate download class with a callback block. The controller creates an instance of the class, and receives the result in the callback, after which, the download class is deallocated. Each call you need to make creates its own instance of the Downloader class, so you don't need to keep track of which response goes with which call.

```
    Downloader *dl = [Downloader new];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"...."]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:10];

    [dl downloadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request completion:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if (!error ) {
            // do whatever you need to do with the raw data here
            NSLog(@"got the data");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@",error);
        }
    }];
```

Here is how I implemented the Downloader class.

```
typedef void(^compBlock)(NSData *data, NSError *error);

@interface Downloader : NSObject <NSURLConnectionDataDelegate>

-(void)downloadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request completion:(compBlock) completion;

@end
```

The implementation file,

```
@interface Downloader()
@property (copy,nonatomic) compBlock completionHandler;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableData *receivedData;
@end

@implementation Downloader

-(void)downloadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *) request completion:(compBlock)completion {
    NSURLConnection *con = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    if (con) {
        self.receivedData = [NSMutableData new];
        self.completionHandler = completion;
    }
}


-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    self.receivedData.length = 0;
}



-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [self.receivedData appendData:data];
}



-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    self.completionHandler(nil, error);
}



-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    self.completionHandler(self.receivedData, nil);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't this method require a synchronous request? Or maybe a synchronous request on a different queue?

Comment: @MichaelKing, no, in the Downloader class, I'm using NSURLConnection with the usual delegate methods. The callback block is called in didFailWithError or connectionDidFinishLoading.

Comment: I didn't realize callback blocks could be in a separate location. I guess I need to read up more on blocks, and how they work. Do you happen to have any good resources off hand?

Comment: @MichaelKing, no, I don't know of any particularly good resource other than Apple's documentation. I can post the code for the downloader class if you'd like to see how I implemented it.

Comment: that would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> My problem, or rather disorganization arises when a controller needs to make more than one API call.

For this kind of thing, you should really look at `NSURLSession` and related classes. `NSURLSession` provides methods like `-sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` that let you complete tasks without having to provide your own delegate object -- the session will provide a default delegate for you, and the default delegate will call your completion handler when the task is done.

You still have the option of providing your own delegate, of course, and each task has an identifier so that your delegate can keep track of which task is which more easily than you can with `NSURLConnection`.

I won't go into all the benefits of `NSURLSession` here because you can [read about them](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW1) yourself, but they're significant. If you're writing new code, you almost certainly should be using `NSURLSession` instead of `NSURLConnection`.